# How can I change color of button in bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap have only 3-4 colors for buttons. How can I change buttons to other colors?

Comment: మీరు మార్చంది మీరు మార్చంది

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a particular button a new css class:

```
.new-button {
  background-color: lightblue; !important
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid the !important is a code smell